# how we can implement this coniditon in django template

Tags: django, if-statement, templates

How i can implement this condition in django template with multiple and or statement in if?

```
 {% if ((email_setting.twitter_link is not None and email_setting.twitter_link != '') 
 or (email_setting.instagram_link is not None and email_setting.instagram_link != '') 
 or (email_setting.fb_link is not None and email_setting.fb_link!= '') ) %}
  Here my body
 {% endif %}
```

this give me an error

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /settings/emailView
Could not parse the remainder: '((email_setting.twitter_link' from '((email_setting.twitter_link'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can expresss this as:

```
{% if email_setting.twitter_link or email_setting.instagram_link or email_setting.fb_link %}
   …
{% endif %}
```

Here we check the truthiness of the `twitter_link` and other settings. The truthiness of `None` and the empty string are `False` whereas for a non-empty string, it is `True`.